# Find best decoding scheme

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I have been studying coding theory and a bit of information theory as well, and found this problem:

Given the channel with channel matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
1/6 & 1/3 & 1/2\\
1/3 & 1/2 & 1/6\\
1/2 & 1/6 & 1/3
\end{bmatrix}
and the following input distribution
$$p(x=0)=0.5,\quad p(x=1)=p(x=2)=0.25$$
find the best decision scheme (for transmission with no coding) and the associated average and maximum probabilities of error.

The associated average of error is given by
$$p_e:=\sum_{c\in C}p(\text{error}|c)p(c)=\sum_{c\in C}\sum_{u\notin B_c}p(u|c)p(c),$$
where $B_c=\{u\in \mathbb{F}_q^n:f(u)=c\}$ and $f:\mathbb{F}_q^n\to C\cup\{*\}$ is the decision scheme ($f(u)=*$ iff $u$ is not decoded).

From a decoder's point of view, we have
$$p_e=\sum_{u\in\mathbb{F}^n_q}p(\text{error})p(u)=1-\sum_{u\in\mathbb{F}_q^n}p(f(u)|u)p(u).$$

And so my goal is to maximize $p(f(u)| u) $ for each $u$. But I'm having some trouble on how to do it and I haven't found much  material on this. Maybe someone could help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the formulas you copied...(eg the $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ looks quite out of place here). I suggest you to try to compute by hand the probabilities of error. 
Say, call the input  $X \in \{A,B,C\}$ and the output $Y \in \{A',B',C'\}$ Suppose you receive $Y=A'$ . Compute the probability of error for the three possible decoding maps $\hat{X} = d(Y)$ (the "no decode" option is clearly irrelevant here).

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you made this problem up yourself? I can't completely understand it. You aren't doing any encoding and want to find the best decoding scheme? You describe your decision as operating on words from $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, but your channel matrix is $3 \times 3$, which suggests either a ternary code or a binary erasure code. You have very high error rates, which seems to suggest you might not be able to make better decisions than just guessing randomly (although it makes sense to never decide "not decoded" because that has a 0% chance of being correct).

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to write something. I didn't make this up, though. I have just edited it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
@leonbloy I computed the backward probabilities matrix ($p(x_i|y_j)$)
\begin{bmatrix}
2/7 & 1/2 & 2/3\\
2/7 & 3/8 & 1/9\\
3/7 & 1/8 & 2/9
\end{bmatrix}
I should now choose by column the greatest values: $p(x_2|y_0)=3/7,\, p(x_0|y_1)=1/2,\, p(x_0,y_2)=2/3$. And so, the best decision scheme would be $f(0)=2,\, f(1)=1,\, f(2)=0$. Is this reasonable

Comment: Yes, that looks right.